Algebraic definition of "normalization"
I believe the notion of a normal form has a proper definition in model theory or algebra.

If you have a set of elements $E$, a premise of there being a normal form is that there are multiple ways to write an element $e \in E$. This suggests we need to distinguish between expressions and their reference. To say that $e_1, e_2$ are equal is to say that although they are not the same expression, they have the same reference. This could suggest one should associate each expression to the element it refers to. For example, the expression $2 + 0$ refers to the element $2$. This would require us to distinguish between the symbol $[2]$ and the concept $2$, and would suggest this theory has two types, $\text{Symbol}$ and $\text{Number}$.

A second approach would be to assume that two expressions $e_1, e_2$ being equal means that according to rewrite rules, they can be unified to the same expression. One says that for a collection of rewrite rules, there exists a sequence $R_i,\ldots,R_j$ which rewrites $e_i$ to $e$, and a sequence $R_k,\ldots,R_l$ which rewrites $e_j$ to $e$. In this case, it is not necessary to assert that $e$ is the same symbol as $e$. This approach does not need a second type, $\text{Number}$, in the theory, and expressions do not need a reference.


I conjecture that there is a way to show the equivalence of the above two theories. In both cases, it is necessary to define the structure of expressions. Terms are inductively defined as elements in the closure of a set of variable symbols $\{v_i, v_j, \ldots \}$ under an application function which, for a function symbol $f_i$ of arity $n$ and selection of $n$ terms, returns the term $f_i(t_0, \ldots, t_n)$. I think a reason to prefer formulation (2) to (1) is that in either case, one must define rules which evaluate an expression $e$, so that (1) needs the rewrite rules of (2) anyway. I wonder if this undermines the idea of an expression's reference, which can only be decided by computation rules. I wonder if therefore, for a collection of expressions, it cannot be said that every expression has a unique reference unless the collection has a confluent and terminating set of rewrite rules. I think there is a connection to be drawn between these ideas and the notion of a representative element of an equivalence class.
